# How do you count pedestrians within a NODE or AREA?

Tags: anylogic

I've successfully counted the number of agents within a coordinate space using a method from a previous post shown here:

[[difficult to find the current location of agents in Anylogic simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688718/difficult-to-find-the-current-location-of-agents-in-anylogic-simulation][1])

```
count(pedGoTo.getPeds(),p->p.getX()>279 && p.getX()<302 && p.getY()>332 && p.getY()<349)
```

However, this method requires me to type in the coordinates. I'd like to count the number of pedestrians inside something I can move around the model, like a Rectangular Node (process modeling library) or Rectangular Area (pedestrian library). Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
count(pedGoTo.getPeds(),p->rectangularArea.contains(p.getX(),p.getY()));
```

Comment: Thank you Felipe, but this results in an error "rectangularArea cannot be resolved". If I use the name of the rectangular area, I get the error "Unreachable code". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have to use the name of the rectangular area obviously... and unreachable code means you are putting this function in the wrong place... but i can't know where...

Comment: Ah ha!! (sorry, new to this). I was putting it directly into "Value" in a Time Plot. I created a function instead and voila! Thank you Felipe!